# Using array of char to pad struct in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I'm writing a simple interpreter in C and I don't want to deal with the memory management so I'm writing a simple memory pool to keep track of and reduce the number malloc's and free's.

```
typedef struct object {

    Type type;
    char data[128];
    struct object* next;

} Object;

typedef struct pool {

    Object* head;
    unsigned int used;
    Object* blocks;

} Pool;
```

As you can see, my memory pool is currently just a linked list of 'Objects' and each object is 128 bytes in size.

My init and malloc functions are below:

```
#define BLOCK_COUNT 256

void* mp_init() {

    Pool* mp = malloc(1 * sizeof(Pool));

    mp->blocks = malloc(BLOCK_COUNT * sizeof(Object));

    mp->head = mp->blocks;
    mp->blocks->next = NULL;
    mp->used = 0;

    return mp;

}

void* mp_malloc(Pool* mp) {

    Object* obj = NULL;
    obj = (mp->blocks + mp->used);
    obj->next = (mp->blocks + (mp->used + 1) );
    obj->next->next = NULL;

    mp->used++;

    return obj;

}
```

I'm using the `char data[128]` to force all of my objects to be 128 bytes in size and my malloc function returns the address of each object and I store whatever I want in those 128 bytes. Is this bad practice? It seems weird to just use an array to increase the size of the struct.

Comment: *"I don't want to deal with the memory management so I'm writing a simple memory pool"* those statements are contradictory.

Comment: @dbush What I mean is, I want to forget about where to call free() because currently I have calls to free() all over the place and I keep getting memory leaks, so I want to use my simple memory pool to stop me having to have free()'s all over the place. My memory pool currently just free's the entire pool when the program finishes execution.

Comment: Your `struct object` is *not* 128 bytes.  According to your declaration It will be `sizeof(Type)+128+sizeof(struct object*)+whatever is required to align your struct`. Ask your compiler its size with a simple `printf5"%d\n",sizeof(struct object);`

Comment: You'll still have to implement a version of `free` to return your structs to the pool. There is no short-cut to proper management. The system `free`s all allocated memory at the end of the program and if that's your reason, you are wasting your time. The good reason for managing a local memory pool for a fixed `struct` type is that it is a lot quicker than constant `malloc` and `free` calls.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider your code bad practice.

1. You do not need a linked list if you have an array (blocks).
2. Calling `malloc(BLOCK_COUNT * sizeof(Object));` in your init method will
   allocate all blocks. This will cause your program to allocate all
   needed memory at the beginning, which can be a waste of memory, if
   you do not exactly know how much memory you are going to need.
3. You still have to manage the memory in your pool, so there is no point of having it.

What you may want to do is to write a garbage collector.
This is however not trivial and would take to long to explain here.

I would advice you to use a different language if you do not want to do the
memory management.

Otherwise what you are probably looking for are arrays of "variants" which have the form:

```
enum type {
    TYPE_1,
    ...
};

struct Object {
    enum type t;
    union {
       type_1 t1;
       ...
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to allocate all the memory your application needs during initialization if:

1. You don't want  your malloc calls to fail due to insufficient memory at run time. (This could be a rare scenario but your application should be robust enough to handle it)
2. Your application cannot tolerate latency introduced by system calls such as malloc and free.

Whether it is a good practice or not depends on the type of application you are working on. From the code snippet you have posted i would like to give couple of comments:

1. For sure you have to implement your own mp_free call to return the freed block back to the memory pool.
2. If your application frees a block in the middle of the list, your mp_malloc should be able to reuse it.
3. If all your threads are accessing the same memory pool, you need to ensure that the calls to mp_malloc and mp_free are made thread safe.

So in short, implementing your own memory management model is a good practice only when your memory manager is robust enough to handle all the above scenarios and many more. Remember that in large scale applications, a bug in a memory manager could be very hard to detect.